# Conditional Poisson Distribution

Tags: distributions, self-study, poisson-distribution, conditional-probability

> The number of claims, $N$, in a year on a portfolio of policies
>   follows a Poisson distribution with parameter $λ$. Large claims have a
>   probability $p$ and small claims $(1-p)$, independently of each other.
>   Suppose we observe $r$ large claims. Show that the conditional
>   distribution of $N-r$ given $r$ is Poisson and find its mean.

I know we can use the definition of a conditional probability and then invoke independence condition on big claims and small claims. But how we find out which PDF does Big claims and small claims follows?

Comment: Please add the `self-study` tag and read ts [tag wiki](stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info), modifying your question if necessary to follow the guidelines there.

Comment: I do not believe the problem as stated has a unique solution. Something more is needed to connect the total number $N$ of claims with the number $L$ of large claims. For instance, $$L|N\sim\mathcal{B}(N,p)\,.$$

Comment: i think your are right, but answer given is as: $$N-r|r\sim\mathcal{Poisson}(\lambda(1-p))$$ How about if we assume that small claims follows Binomial distribution then how can we simplify it using definition of conditional probability.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $X$ and $Y$ denote the number of large claims and small claims respectively
in an year. Then, $N = X+Y$ is the total number of claims and is known to
be a Poisson$(\lambda)$ random variable. Now, *given* that $N=n$, the
conditions stated in the problem tell us that the *conditional*
distribution of $X$ is binomial with parameters $(n,p)$ and that of $Y$
is binomial with parameters $(n,1-p)$. Note that *conditioned on* $N=n$, $X$ and $Y$ are very much *dependent* random variables since $Y=n-X$. 
But, *unconditionally*,
$X$ and $Y$ are *independent* Poisson$(\lambda p)$ and Poisson$(\lambda(1-p))$
random variables.

To see why all this is so, consider that for $0 \leq r \leq n$,
$$P\{X=r, Y=s \mid N=n\}
= \begin{cases} \displaystyle\binom{n}{r}p^r(1-p)^{s}, & \text{if} ~s = n-r,\\
0, & \text{if} ~ s \neq n-r.
\end{cases}$$
Consequently, for any $r, s \geq 0$,
$$\begin{align}
P\{X = r, Y = s\} &= \sum_{n=0}^\infty P\{X=r, Y=s, N=n\}\\
&= \sum_{n=0}^\infty P\{X=r, Y=s \mid N=n\}P\{N =n\}\\
&=\binom{r+s}{r}p^r(1-p)^{s}e^{-\lambda}\frac{\lambda^{r+s}}{(r+s)!}
&\scriptstyle{\text{only the $n=r+s$ term is nonzero in the sum}}\\
&= \frac{(r+s)!}{r!s!}(\lambda p)^r(\lambda(1-p))^{s}
e^{-\lambda p - \lambda(1-p)}\frac{1}{(r+s)!}\\
&= e^{-\lambda p}\frac{(\lambda p)^r}{r!}\cdot 
e^{-\lambda(1-p)}\frac{(\lambda(1-p))^s}{s!}\\
&= P\{X=r\}P\{Y = s\}
\end{align}$$
showing that $X$ and $Y$ are independent Poisson$(\lambda p)$ and
Poisson$(\lambda(1-p))$ random variables respectively. Consequently, *conditioned*
on $X = r$, $Y$ continues to be a Poisson$(\lambda(1-p))$ random variable.