# $N \sim$ Poisson iff number of heads & tails independent?

Tags: probability, distributions, binomial-distribution, poisson-distribution

Consider $N$ to be the total number of fair coin tosses such that $N \sim \mathrm{Pois}(\lambda) $.

Then for the <s>events</s> (sorry) random variables defined as, $A:$ No. of heads observed and $B:$ No. of tails observed.

And A, B independent i.e., $P(A)P(B)=P(A \cap B)$.

My questions are:

1. Is that line of logic bidirectional? If we only know N follows some arbitrary probability distribution, but we do know that A and B are independent is it true that N **must** follow a Poisson distribution.
   I've been told that the answer to this is yes and it's an example of a Poisson point process (?) but I'm unsure how to go about proving it. I haven't studied stochastic processes so I really don't know anything about Poisson point processes.

My initial thought was to use the law of total probability on P(A) and P(B) since we know P(A|N=n) would follow a Binomial distribution. But this didn't seem to lead anywhere.

2. Whats special about the Poisson distribution? Why does it seem to be so intrinsic in this problem?

(PS: I'm a math major and I don't have a great probability theory background I've taken a measure theory course but that's about it.)

Comment: Can you explain better the experimental setup? But anyhow, isn't $N=A+B$ so $A, B$ cannot be independent

Comment: @Kjetil They cannot be *conditionally* independent, you mean.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are describing is known as *thinning property* of Poisson random variables (or Poisson processes), also *Poisson splitting*. Usually, only  one way of the claim is stated and proved, namely that the number $A$ of successes and the number $B$ of fails from $N$ Bernoulli experiments are independent and actually also Poisson distributed if $N$ has a Poisson distribution.
No particular tools are needed to prove this statement, see for example the  [answer by @DilipSarwate](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/140833/237561) here on cv.

> 1. Is that line of logic bidirectional? If we only know N follows some arbitrary probability distribution, but we do know that A and B are independent is it true that N **must** follow a Poisson distribution.
>    I've been told that the answer to this is yes and it's an example of a Poisson point process (?) but I'm unsure how to go about proving it.

The converse that you asked for, namely that that independence of $A$ and $B$ only is possible if $N$ has a Poisson distribution, is true! Nevertheless, it is rarely mentioned; the only source popping up on Google are some [lecture notes by S.S.Mukherjee](https://soumendu041.gitlab.io/notes/Poisson.pdf) that lead students through a proof by breaking it down into smaller steps.

This proof uses a powerful, yet simple tool from probability theory: [*probability generating functions (pgf)*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability-generating_function). Pgfs characterize a distribution uniquely. From the conditional distributions of $A\mid N$ and $B\mid N$, one can derive a formula that relates the pgf of $N$ to the pgfs of the unconditional distributions of $A$ and $B$. For the final step, a theorem from Mathematical Analysis is applied, stating that solutions to [Cauchy's functional equations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%27s_functional_equation) are of a particular form.

> 2. Whats special about the Poisson distribution? Why does it seem to be so intrinsic in this problem?

The Poisson distribution is indeed very special. It is as important to discrete variables on $\mathbb{N}_0^+$ as the Normal distribution is to continuous variables. One of the properties of the Poisson distribution is [infinite divisibility](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Infinite_divisibility_(probability)): a Poisson r.v. with mean $\lambda$ can be written as the sum of arbitrary many independent r.v.s that also have a Poisson distribution, each with mean $\lambda / m$ if there are $m$ summands. The Poisson distribution is not the only distribution with this property, but other infinitely divisible random variables can be expressed as a sum of "Poisson many" i.i.d. random variables. The distributions of such sums are called [compound Poisson distributions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compound_Poisson_distribution). Maybe this relates a bit to the thinning property, in that
you may consider the random variables $A$ or $B$ here as a compound Poisson, constructed by summing up Bernoulli random variables.

Comment: On a careful reading of the linked notes, it appears that it is not enough that $A$ and $B$ be independent; they must be independent *Binomial* variates, and the probability parameter for $B$ must equal $1 - $ the probability parameter for $A$.  (Look at Exercise 5; you will see the probability parameter associated with $z_2$ equals $1 - $ the one associated with $z_1$.)

Comment: Yes, @jbowman, indeed $A$ and $B$ are binomial, *conditioned on $N$*. In the question, $A$ is the number of heads (thus $p=1/2$) and $B$ is the number of tails (thus with probability $1-1/2=1/2$.). One can generalize this to unfair coins with probability of heads $p\neq 1/2$. By unconditioning, $A$ and $B$ become independent - this is Poisson magic.

Comment: By unconditioning, $A$ and $B$ can become independent regardless of whether $N$ is Poisson.  Any two independent RVs sum to *something*; conditional upon the value of that *something*, they have a conditional distribution.   If you uncondition, you get back the two original distributions, which can be anything.   It doesn't have anything to do with the Poisson distribution at all.

Comment: @jbowman, The question says: Consider N to be the total number of fair coin tosses such that N∼Pois(λ). Then for the events defined as, A: No. of heads observed and B:
 No. of tails observed." - it should probably have been "random variables" instead of "events", but I read this as: $N$ is Poisson, $A\mid N \sim \text{Bin}(N, 0.5)$. So the definition is by conditional distribution. After unconditioning, $A$ and $B$ would not be independent if $N$ was something else than Poisson (this claim is the converse asked for in the question).

Comment: Oh wow thanks for those lecture notes!  I do remember learning generating functions, they make for such slick proofs. I will read through the notes to understand the thinning in detail. Its been a while since I did any statistics so my terminology in the question was a bit wonky.

The other answer had confused me considerably. Unfortunately I didn't phrase my question accurately.  I thought infinite support of N was implied, and if $N=\{ 0,1,2\}$ surely you'd need to consider A, B taking the value of $2$ as a possibility.

Comment: You need not rule out distributions with finite support - the question is complete as is, and very interesting as it is rarely stated that this characterizes the Poisson distribution. The only point I stumbled upon at first read was "events" A and B. If you confirm that you indeed meant the random number, I will edit my answer and replace X and Y by A and B :-)

Comment: Yes i made the change in the post that was a mistake on my part their random variables not events.

Comment: Now I believe the confusion actually came from the title, but I don't think you should change it because the other answer would then look strange.

Answer (score 1):

$A$ and $B$ independent does not imply that $N$ follows a Poisson distribution.  Consider $A, B \sim \text{Bernoulli}(0.5)$; the probability function for $N = A+B$ is clearly not Poisson, as $N \in \{0,1,2\}$ but the domain of the Poisson distribution is the nonnegative integers.

The conditional probability distribution of, e.g., $A|N$ is obviously also not Poisson.

Edit in response to comments:

Observe that the conditional distribution of $A|N=0$ is, as it is regardless of the distribution of $N$, a point mass at $0$.  This is equivalent to $A \sim \text{Binomial}(1,0)$.

When $N=1$, the conditional distribution of $A|N$ is $\text{Bernoulli}(0.5)$, which is the same as a $\text{Binomial}(1,0.5)$ distribution.  This comes about because either $A$ or $B$ must equal $1$, but not both; since $P(A=1) = P(B=1)$, it follows that $P(A=1|N=1) = P(B=1|N=1) = 0.5$, and of course the event $B=1$ is the same as the event $A=0$.

When $N=2$, it must be that $A=B=1$, the distributions of which can be thought of as $\text{Binomial}(1,1)$.

Therefore we can conclude that the conditional distribution of $A|N$ in this example is Binomial with size parameter equal to $1$ and probability parameter equal to $N/2$.

Consequently, it is not the case that a conditional Binomial distribution for $A|N$ implies, with the assumptions, that $N \sim \text{Poisson}$.

Comment: But what if A |N is binomial with size parameter N and fixed p, B = N-A, and A, B are unconditionally independent. Does this imply that N has a Poisson distribution? I can't see how your example disproves the assertion.

Comment: Your assertion was "we do know that A and B are unconditionally independent",  not that $A$ and $B$ are independent Binomial variates.  However, by happy chance, we can observe that in my example $A, B \sim \text{Binomial}(1,0.5)$, as the Bernoulli distribution is a Binomial distribution with size parameter equal to one, so the example does disprove the assertion.

Comment: Well, I also first interpreted the 1. question isolated from the introductory paragraph, but I think it is meant including the definitions given in the start. That is A has binomial distribution conditional on N, and B = N - A. Independence is only when unconditioned.

Comment: @Ute - I'm not following you.  The question seems clear: the only assumption made is that "A and B are unconditionally independent."  The mention of the Binomial distribution comes in when the OP describes their approach, but there's no mention of it as an assumption in the question part of the post.

Comment: It was not clearly stated as assumption, but the first sentence says: "Consider N
 to be the total number of fair coin tosses such that N∼Pois(λ).  
Then for the events defined as, A:
 No. of heads observed and B:
 No. of tails observed. " I took "events" as a typo meaning r.v.s in reality

Comment: @Ute - maybe I'm being obtuse, but the question is "If we only know N follows some arbitrary probability distribution, but we do know that A and B are independent is it true that N must follow a Poisson distribution."  I don't see how the fact that *if* $N\sim \text{Poisson}$ *then* $A \sim \text{Binomial}$ appears there.  But maybe it's just me.

Comment: Jbowman, let's say, the question allows different interpretations. It is not exactly formally statet.

Comment: @Ute - I think I've addressed your point in the revision!